# How can simplify node script

Tags: node.js

The code is:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const output = [];
let i = 0;
const inputString = "/h1/h2/h3/h4";
_.forEach(inputString.split('/').filter(e => e), (f, key, res) => {
  if (i < res.length - 1  ) {
        output.push(`/${_.slice(res, 0, i += 1).join('/')}`);
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

The expect output is array and skip last one : ['/h1', '/h1/h2' , '/h1/h2/h3']

How can i simplify it ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to `split` the string into the `h`s, slice off the empty string in the first position, and `pop()` the last. Then, `.map` the resulting array by `join`ing indicies 0 to 0, then 0 to 1, then 0 to 2, etc:

```js
const inputString = "/h1/h2/h3/h4";
const items = inputString.split('/').slice(1); // slice to remove empty string at [0]
items.pop(); // remove last item (h4)
const output = items.map((_, i) => '/' + items.slice(0, i + 1).join('/'));
console.log(output);
```

No external library required

As comment notes, another way would be to find all indicies of `/`:

```js
const inputString = "/h1/h2/h3/h4";
const slashIndicies = [...inputString].reduce((a, char, i) => {
  if (char === '/') a.push(i);
  return a;
}, []);
// ignore first leading slash:
slashIndicies.shift();
const output = slashIndicies.map((slashIndex) => inputString.slice(0, slashIndex));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Your joins are backwards.  You have `h3` as a lone element and he is asking for `h1`.

Comment: This can also be done without split and join. All that is needed is the indexes of the `/`s and skipping the first, one can slice to each one.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant:

```js
'use strict';

const inputString = '/h1/h2/h3/h4';

const arr = [...inputString].reduce((acc, ch) => {
  if (ch === '/') acc.push(`${acc[acc.length - 1] || ''}${ch}`);
  else acc[acc.length - 1] += ch;
  return acc;
}, []).slice(0, -1);

console.log(arr);
```